# Should browserify be in deps or devdeps?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, browserify

I have a browserify app and it includes a few transforms. This app might be a top level app or a plugin. I put browserify transforms in deps because the app that `require()` my plugin might not include these transforms. But should I also put browserfiy in deps? I don't think a server side app would `require()` a browserify app as npm doesn't support transforms (so the browserify app might need to be pre-compiled before a server app can use it). If a client side app wants to `require()` my plugin it's most likely a browserify app and already include browserify in its deps or devdeps. So I don't think browserify should be in deps but devdeps but my co-worker says otherwise. Also I always use browserify as a top level app but no experience if it's a plugin. I can't find any relative reference online. If you have experience with browserify app as a plugin that would be great. Thanks

Comment: Depends on how you deploy your code. I usually use browserify as a dev dependency because I deploy my app pre-built to the production environment rather than building it in the production environment.

Comment: If you're developing a module, I don't see why you would include browserify at all, whatever is including it should handle that.

Comment: I agree @KevinB, my co-worker actually brought this up and I couldn't find any reference about it.